# "git show" shows strange characters on XTerm

Tags: freebsd, git, xterm

On FreeBSD 10.3, I run a command like `git show` on `xterm`, the output contains some strange irrelevant characters as below. I'm not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your pager seems to be configured to render the Esc character (used in escape sequences to change the text colour) as `ESC` instead of passing it directly to the terminal (that's independent from the terminal emulator, in your case `xterm`).

Try setting (`sh` syntax).

```
PAGER=less LESS=R
export PAGER LESS
```

Or (`(t)csh` syntax):

```
setenv PAGER less
setenv LESS R
```

To select GNU `less` as your pager and tell `less` to pass text formatting escape sequences through. If you don't set the `LESS` variable, `git` sets it to `FRX` (so includes `R` already, but also `F` and `X` which you may want as well). So you may want to omit that part if you prefer the `FRX` behaviour (see `less` man page for details), or `unset LESS` it if you had it set to a different value, or set it yourself to `FRX`.

That `PAGER` environment variable is used by a few things (like `man`) beside `git`. If you want to change your pager only for `git`, you can set the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable instead.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
git config --global core.pager 'less -FRX'
```

You can tell `git` to not use colour when using a pager with:

```
git config --global color.pager false
```

See `env PAGER=less git config --help` for details.

Comment: The `git config` solution works with Cygwin xterm.  Thank you. +1